# Couldn't Find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3

Tags: android

I have got a problem when importing 2048 project.Please Help Me

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-alpha3/gradle-2.0.0-alpha3.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-alpha3/gradle-2.0.0-alpha3.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-alpha3/gradle-2.0.0-alpha3.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-alpha3/gradle-2.0.0-alpha3.jar
Required by:
    :2048-android-master:unspecified
```

Comment: Download Android Studio 2.0 beta2 and use 2.0.0-beta2 gradle plugin. And open SDK manager and update everything.

Comment: thank you ! my problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Update

[image]

version 2.0.0-beta4 is now available

Version 2.0.0-beta3 of the android gradle plugin is not released yet.

[image]

The current latest version (to use with Android-Studio 1.3-preview) is 1.3.0-beta1.

Put this in your root build.gradle

buildscript {
     ...
     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta4'

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}
You can find the latest published version of the plugin on this page: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Note that you may also need to update your build tools :

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.programming"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}
This version of the build tools is available with the sdk manager under section "Tools (preview channel)"

pm. you clear